# JSON and Android Studio

Tags: java, android, json

My API : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=45.067381,%202.988574&destinations=45.067381,%202.988574&mode=driving&language=en-US&sensor=false

My code on android studio :

```
private class GetDistance extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=45.067381,%202.988574&destinations=45.067381,%202.988574&mode=driving&language=en-US&sensor=false");

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                JSONObject contacts = jsonObj.getJSONObject("rows");

                JSONArray childrenArray = contacts.getJSONArray("elements");


                for (int i = 0; i < childrenArray.length(); i++) {



                    JSONObject childrenData  = childrenArray.getJSONObject(i);






                    String json_distance = childrenData.getString("status");


                    test58 = json_distance;



                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }
        } else {}
        return null;
    }
```

> > > Error : Json parsing error: Value [{"elements":[{"distance":{"text":"1 m","value":0},"duration":{"text":"1 min","value":0},"status":"OK"}]}] at rows of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

How do I get access to rows -> elements -> distance -> text ?

Thanks.

Comment: `JSONObject contacts = jsonObj.getJSONObject("rows");`

The Key *"rows"* returns an array and not an Object.

Comment: And then parse the remaining JSON.

Comment: I do not know how to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JSONObject contacts = jsonObj.getJSONObject("rows");`

The Key "rows" returns an array and not an Object.

Change the above statement to

`JSONArray rowArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("rows");`

Now select the first element in  *rowArray* array

```
JSONObject firstRow = rowArray.getJSONObject(0);
```

From this object obtain the array associated with *elements* key

`JSONArray elementArray = firstRow.getJSONArray("elements");`

Then,

```
JSONObject firstElement = elementArray.getJSONObject(0);
JSONObject  distance = firstElement.getJSONObject("distance");
String text = distance.getString("text");
```

Comment: Make sure u understand it. Don't just copy and paste. Learn how to traverse JSON response. If u need my help let me know otherwise everything is there on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

My new code :

```
if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {

                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonStr);


                JSONArray rows = object.getJSONArray("rows");

                JSONArray elements = rows.getJSONArray("elements");

                JSONObject distance = elements.getJSONObject("distance");

                test58 = distance.getString("text");



            }
```

error with rows.getJSONArray("elements") and elements.getJSONObject("distance")

**getJsonArray (int) in JsonArray cannot be applied to (java.lang.string)**

Answer (score 0):

this is idea        @Override

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        System.out.println("Menu doInBackground");
        ParseJson parseJson = new ParseJson(); 
        JSONObject jsonObject = parseJson.getJsonFromURL("YOUR LINK");
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("rows");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
               JSONObject jsonObjectRow = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
               for(int j= 0; j< jsonObjectRow; j++){
                JSONObject jsonObjectElements = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
                ....
                for(int k = 0; k< jsonObjectElements; k++){
                JSONObject jsonObjectDistance = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
                ...

                }

               }

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
```

your Model

```
public class MyModel{
    private String[] destinationAddress;
    private String[] originAddresses;
    private List<Row> listRow;
    private String status;


        public  class Row{
            private String estatus;
            private List<Elements> listElements;


            public class Elements{
                private List<Distance> distance;

                public class Distance {
                    private String text;
                    private int value;

                    public Distance(String text, int value) {
                        this.text = text;
                        this.value = value;
                    }

                    public String getText() {
                        return text;
                    }

                    public void setText(String text) {
                        this.text = text;
                    }

                    public int getValue() {
                        return value;
                    }

                    public void setValue(int value) {
                        this.value = value;
                    }
                }

                public Elements(List<Distance> distance) {
                    this.distance = distance;
                }

                public List<Distance> getDistance() {
                    return distance;
                }

                public void setDistance(List<Distance> distance) {
                    this.distance = distance;
                }
            }

            public Row(String estatus, List<Elements> listElements) {
                this.estatus = estatus;
                this.listElements = listElements;
            }

            public String getEstatus() {
                return estatus;
            }

            public void setEstatus(String estatus) {
                this.estatus = estatus;
            }

            public List<Elements> getListElements() {
                return listElements;
            }

            public void setListElements(List<Elements> listElements) {
                this.listElements = listElements;
            }
        }
        public MyModel(String[] destinationAddress, String[] originAddresses, List<Row> listRow, String status) {
            this.destinationAddress = destinationAddress;
            this.originAddresses = originAddresses;
            this.listRow = listRow;
            this.status = status;
        }

        public String[] getDestinationAddress() {
            return destinationAddress;
        }

        public void setDestinationAddress(String[] destinationAddress) {
            this.destinationAddress = destinationAddress;
        }

        public String[] getOriginAddresses() {
            return originAddresses;
        }

        public void setOriginAddresses(String[] originAddresses) {
            this.originAddresses = originAddresses;
        }

        public List<Row> getListRow() {
            return listRow;
        }

        public void setListRow(List<Row> listRow) {
            this.listRow = listRow;
        }

        public String getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public void setStatus(String status) {
            this.status = status;
        }
    }
```